# Tomcat MYSQL Connection still exist after tomcat restart

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I have two tomcat server.

---

the first one is 192.168.123.181, version tomcat-7.0.40

### [192.168.123.181](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hnNR.png)

And the second one is 192.168.123.80, version tomcat-9.0.12

### [192.168.123.81](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT90q.png)

I find that when I try to restart the tomcat service for 192.168.123.80, the mysql connection will not be auto-close/auto-release, which always result in this mySQL Error - "Too many connection".

When I enter "service tomcat stop" for 192.168.123.80, the console will show the following message:

> Using CATALINA_BASE:   /apps/tomcat
>
> Using CATALINA_HOME:   /apps/tomcat
>
> Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /apps/tomcat/temp
>
> Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
>
> Using CLASSPATH:       /apps/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/apps/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
>
> Kill failed: $CATALINA_PID not set

However, when I enter the same command in 192.168.123.181, it will show the following message:

> Using CATALINA_BASE:   /apps/tomcat
>
> Using CATALINA_HOME:   /apps/tomcat
>
> Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /apps/tomcat/temp
>
> Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
>
> Using CLASSPATH:       /apps/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/apps/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
>
> Using CATALINA_PID:    /var/run/tomcat.pid
>
> Killing Tomcat with the PID: 18360

May somebody teach me how can I config the server so that it will release the mySQL connection after I restart the tomcat service?

** This is how I connect to mysql server,

code at SLO class:

```
con = ConnectionPool.getConnection();
```

code at ConnectionPool class,

```
 public static Connection getConnection(){

     return connectionManager.getConnection();
 }


public static class ConnectionManager {

    public Connection getConnection(String driverClass, String driverUrl) {

        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("proxool." + POOLALIAS + ":" + driverClass + ":" + driverUrl;);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.err_sys("ConnectionPool.getConnection(): Error -" + e);
        } 
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code to connect mysql server.

Comment: Are you sing a DBCP? Do you have some Threads that have not terminated?

Comment: Also, share the complete MySQL error - "Too many connection".

Comment: so do you `close` the connection?